# What does -D indicate in maven command?

Tags: maven

Can anyone explain what -D indicates in maven command:  `mvn clean install -DskipTests`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You define a property that can be read by a [Maven Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html) or [being used inside the pom](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties).

```
$> mvn --help

usage: mvn [options] [] []

Options:
 ...
 -D,--define                       Define a system property
 ...
```

In this particular case you tell the [`maven-surefire-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/skipping-test.html) to skip tests.